# "Have you ever read" versus "have you never read"

Tags: grammaticality

> "Have you *ever* read Jane Jacobs's The Death and Life of Great American Cities?" he asked. (The New York Times)

I don't know why, but if I wrote that question I would have used *never*, not *ever*, but, alas, I would have made a mistake. In fact, looking for "have you never read" on reliable Internet sites, I found a few occurences of this expression, mostly in the Bible.

However I believe of having understood that "You have never read" is correct; what it is unclear is as to whether that "never" has to be replaced with "ever" when that sentence is posed in question form. Is it?

Please, in reference to the "ever" and the "never" usage  explain how are different the following two questions, maybe comparing the affirmative forms:

- Have you **never** read [...]?
- Have you **ever** read [...]?

Comment: The difference of those sentence is the same there is in Italian, where you say _Hai mai letto [...]?_ instead of "Have you ever read [...]?" and _Non hai mai letto [...]?_ instead of "Have you never read [...]?"

Comment: @kiam, thank you for your very instructive comment!

Answer (score 11):

*Have you **ever** read ... ?* is a simple question, asking if you are familiar with the work.

*Have you **never** read ... ?* is an incredulous response to your betraying unfamiliarity with the work:

> "Have you never read such-and-such? I am amazed that a man of your evident scholarly attainments should be so ignorant."

It is more colloquially expressed as *Haven't you ever read ... ?*

Comment: Yeah. You could probably always discard *ever*, which is really just an intensifier. And *never* is just a "negator", so really the pair to be considered are semantically equivalent to *"**Do** you love me?"* and *"**Don't** you love me?"* But neither of those is exactly a "simple question", in most real-world contexts. The difference is that framing such questions in the negative implies *I'm expecting the answer to be "No", but that's not the answer I would have preferred*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If it comes to that, the ordinary versions where I come from would be "Djever read X?" and "Shiyut, yu never read X?"

Comment: +1, as incredulity is exactly the emotion injected by changing _ever_ to _never_.

Answer (score -1):

> Have you ever read this book?
>   No, I have never read it.

And also say "I have ever read . . ." Both are same.

Comment: Please don't use all caps here, it's like shouting.

Comment: 1. No shouting please. 2. No, they're not the same. Here "I have ever read it" is ungrammatical.

Comment: @AmudalaSatyanarayana lol......